# Polynomial of degree 5 divisible by other polynomials.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I need some help with a problem.

Find a polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $5$ such that both of these properties hold:

1. $f(x)-1$ is divisible by $(x-1)^3$.
2. $f(x)$ is divisible by $x^3$.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this...

Answer (score 3):

You know that $f(x)$ is 5th-degree and is divisible by $x^3$.  So write $$f(x) = x^3(ax^2 + bx+c).$$

The other condition is that $f(x) -1$ is divisible by $(x-1)^3$.  So we have $$ x^3(ax^2 + bx+c)-1 = (x-1)^3q(x).$$

Evidently $q(x)$ is also second degree.

Simplify  and equate coefficients on both sides to solve for $a,b,c$.

Comment: Couldn't it be $cx^3(ax^2+bx+c)$?

Comment: @BobJoe: You can absorb the coefficient of $x^3$ into the other coefficients.

Comment: Oh, true.  Thanks.

Comment: I still do not understand; what is the final answer?

Answer (score 3):

You know $f(x) = x^3 g(x)$ for some polynomial $g$ of degree 2.

You know $f(x) = (x-1)^3 h(x)+1$ for some polynomial $h$ of degree 2.

So, you need to figure out either $g$ or $h$.

Using the second equation we have $f(1) = 1$, so $g(1) = 1$.

Differentiating the equations gives
$f'(x) = 3 x^2 g(x) + x^3 g'(x) = 3 (x-1)^2 h(x) + (x-1)^3 h'(x)$,
from which we get $f'(1) = 3 g(1)+ g'(1) = 0$. This lets us compute $g'(1)$.

Repeating one more time gives us
$f''(x) = 6xg(x)+ 3 x^2 g'(x) + 3 x^2 g'(x) + x^3 g''(x) = (x-1) j(x)$
for some polynomial $j$,
from which get
$6g(1)+6g'(1)+ g''(1) = 0$.
This lets us compute $g''(1)$.

Knowing $g(1),g'(1), g''(1)$ lets you compute $g$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\  x^3\mid 1\!+(x\!-\!1)^3(a\!+\!bx\!+\!cx^2)\, =\, \color{#c00}{1\!-\!a} + (\color{#0a0}{3a\!-\!b})\,x + (\color{blue}{3b\!-\!3a\!-\!c})\,x^2 +\, \cdots$

$\!\iff \color{#c00}{a=1}\ \, $ and $\, \ 0 =\color{#0a0}{3a\!-\!b} = 3\!-\!b\!\iff\! b=3\ \, $ and $\, \  0 =\color{blue}{3b\!-\!3a\!-\!c} = 6\!-\!c\!\iff\!c=6\ \ $ **QED**

**Remark** $ $ i.e. $\,x^3\mid f\!\iff\!$ power series for $\,f\,$ has order $\ge 3\!\iff\!$ coef's of $\,\color{#c00}{x^0},\,\color{#0a0}{x^1},\color{blue}{x^2}$ are all $\,0$.